# Background-image obstructs a-href

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap and am trying to have a `div` as the background image behind many other divs, however I have noticed that when I put  the background image on the parent div, all `a-href` elements become unclickable. Here is the code that replicates it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background: url('http://images.alphacoders.com/225/225771.jpg'); z-index:-100;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="color:white;">
        <a href="www.google.ca">Why can't you click me?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f8e7n4f6/

How can I have a background image behind my divs and maintain the integrity of my `a-href` tags? And, I'm a bit curious as to why it prevents `a-href` from being clickable.

Comment: No need of negative `z-index` on div. Just remove it. it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting negative z-index to the div holding the link `<a>` tag which is pushing it to the back and preventing it from being clicked:

This part in the below code:

`<div class="col-md-12" style="background: url('http://images.alphacoders.com/225/225771.jpg'); z-index:-100; ">`

FULL HTML:

```
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background: url('http://images.alphacoders.com/225/225771.jpg'); z-index:-100; ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="color:white;">
        <a href="www.google.ca">Why can't you click me?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't think you really need this property, you can remove it unless you are performing specific styling we are not aware of..

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/f8e7n4f6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the z-index of the image to 1